# Getting correct local time zone to display for end-users in Django web app

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner in Django. Time zone in my settings.py file is set to 'UTC'. End users of my web app hail from India and Mexico - two very different time zones. I have a comments template where I display comments like so:

```
{% get_comment_list for object as comment_list %}
    {% for comment in comment_list reversed %}
    <p>
    <div class="comment">
    <a href="{% url 'profile' slug=comment.user_name %}">{{ comment.user_name }}</a>
      {{ ':' }}
      {{ comment.comment }}
      </div>
     <div class="date">
     {{ comment.submit_date }}
     </div>
     </p>
    {% endfor %}
```

I've tried `{% load tz %}` at the top and then trying to convert comment.submit_date to local time via `{% localtime on %}`, but it merely spouts out UTC for me.

How do I make sure my users in India and Mexico see their local timestamps when they comment?

Comment: That is not enough to see where the problem is. Follow [Django Time Zone docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/) to detect what you are doing wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the use of {% localtime on %} is correct, but you need to activate your user's timezone before you can use that. Django does not automatically knows your user's tz.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate

```
# py
settings.TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
timezone.activate('us/estern')

# template
{% localtime on %}
{{ datetime }} <= this time will be in estern standard time
```

Comment: So for this to work, I'll need end users to select their timezones manually, and then pass on that as an argument to `timezone.activate()`? No automatic solution here eh?

Comment: there are a few ways one way is user select, use ip, gps coordinate or use javascript and retreive the browser tz and write it to the cookie and on the server side you can use a timezone middleware to activate the timezone.

Comment: I did as Du D said, and it's worked for me. But be careful I spent the whole day trying to catch the problem. It will depends on your pytz plugin, I had an old version. You need to update it via --upgrage. I found the solution randomly..