# Django Convert server date to local date

Tags: python, django

Lets say i have a server date of format `DD-MM-YYYY` 
(got it from timezone) how can i change it to the corresponding date of the user?

It should show the corresponding date with respect to the users time zone

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439119/getting-correct-local-time-zone-to-display-for-end-users-in-django-web-app). This is possible a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

When I occured a same problem I tried all sorts of different solutions.

Simplest is to add `{{ created|date:"d-M-Y G:i" }}` in your templates. You can format it anyway you want despite the format at the base. That is if it is onlya display issue.

You can try to set a default format in your settings.py

```
DATE_FORMAT = 'd-m-Y'
TIME_FORMAT = 'H:i'
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'd-m-Y H:i'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'

MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'F j'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y P'
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 1

# BUT here use the Python strftime format syntax,
# LIST: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%d-%m-%Y',     # '21-03-2014'
)
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%H:%M:%S',     # '17:59:59'
    '%H:%M',        # '17:59'
)
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S',# '21-03-2014 17:59'
    '%d-%m-%Y',
)
```

..and use some of those for you forms.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:-

```
settings.py:-

    settings.TIME_ZONE = 'Your Timezone'

views.py :-


    from django.utils.timezone import localtime

    result = localtime(some_time_object)
```

`localtime` will convert date object in the time_zone you have set in `settings.py`, by default it will use 'America/Chicago'