# How Do I Convert UTC Time To User's Local Time in Django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-templates

These answers didn't help:

1. [Getting correct local time zone to display for end-users in Django web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439119/getting-correct-local-time-zone-to-display-for-end-users-in-django-web-app)
2. [Django different timezones in same application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135190/django-different-timezones-in-same-application)

All datetime data is stored in UTC in my database.

I would like each of my users to see the datetime in their local timezone instead of UTC. I've tried the code below:

**settings.py**

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_TZ = True
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from home_app import models
from django.utils import timezone
import pytz

def home_view(request):
    timezone.activate(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
    sample_queryset = models.TimeModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'sample_queryset': sample_queryset,})
```

**home.html**

```
{% for row in sample_queryset %}
    {% load tz %}
    {% localtime on %}
    {{ row.time }}
    {% endlocaltime %}
{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class TimeModel(models.Model):
    sample_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.time) + ' ' + self.sample_text
```

However, after all, the same UTC time from the database is being printed.

**Other details:**

Django 1.11

SQLite (for now; will use Postgres in production)

Python 3.6.8

Comment: Can you try this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#timezone.

Comment: Tried it already. No luck.

Comment: Will you please take a look? @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have migrated to Postgres from SQLite and made the following changes:

**models.py**

***Before:***

from django.db import models

```
class TimeModel(models.Model):
    sample_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) # changed time to dt

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.time) + ' ' + self.sample_text
```

***After:***

```
from django.db import models

class TimeModel(models.Model):
    sample_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) # changed time to dt

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.dt) + ' ' + self.sample_text
```

Answer (score 2):

Valid timeZone values are based on the tz (timezone) database used by Linux and other Unix systems. The values are strings (xsd:string) in the form “**Area/Location**,” in which:

**Area** is a continent or ocean name. Area currently includes:

- Africa
- America (both North America and South America)
- Antarctica
- Arctic
- Asia
- Atlantic
- Australia
- Europe
- Etc (administrative zone. For example, “Etc/UTC” represents
  Coordinated Universal Time.)
- Indian
- Pacific

**Location** is the city, island, or other regional name.

The zone names and output abbreviations adhere to POSIX (portable operating system interface) UNIX conventions, which uses positive (+) signs west of Greenwich and negative (-) signs east of Greenwich, which is the opposite of what is generally expected. For example, “Etc/GMT+4” corresponds to 4 hours behind UTC (that is, west of Greenwich) rather than 4 hours ahead of UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) (east of Greenwich).

[Here is a list all valid timezones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJmzp.png)

You can change time zone in your settings.py as follows

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks in your template code, it should be something like

```
{% for row in sample_queryset %}
    {% load tz %}
    {% timezone timezone_string %}
    {{ row.time }}
    {% endtimezone %}

{% endfor %}
```

I suspect as per here [localtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#localtime) the timezone getting picked up for you is UTC from settings.py
You should use this instead [timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#timezone)